# 3rd Party WPF Treeview Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, treeview

I am wondering if anyone knows of a WPF control that can serve the following functions.

1. Is a treeview that contains treenodes
2. Can display different numbers of treeviews depending on how wide the parent window is expanded
3. Can be bound with an ItemSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the DevExpress TreeList control:
http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Tree_List/

Or
Telerik's TreeView control:
http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treeview.aspx

Check out their demos and you can even download and try them.